# how to assign a model instance to a class property in django

Tags: python, django, class

thanks first!
I met a problem when using custom class,here is the code:
class definition:

```
class BaseCompetition:
    def __init__(self, company):
        self.company = company
class SingleLeagueCompetition(Competition):
    def __init__(self, company):
    BaseCompetition.__init__(self,company)
```

when using it,like this:

```
test_company = Company.objects.get(id=1)
sample_single = SingleLeagueCompetition(test_company)
```

'Company' is a model.
But I got a error when executing the code,like this:
I just don't know what's wrong...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/littlep/myWorks/python-works/sports_with_zeal/swz/dao.py", line 32, in __init__
self.company = company
File "/Users/littlep/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 639, in __set__
if instance._state.db is None:
AttributeError: 'SingleLeagueCompetition' object has no attribute '_state'
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SingleLeagueCompetition` class should inherit from `BaseCompetition`, like this:

```
class BaseCompetition:
    def __init__(self, company):
        self.company = company
class SingleLeagueCompetition(BaseCompetition):
    def __init__(self, company):
        super().__init__(company)
```

also instead of call constructor  by using parent  class `BaseCompetition._init_`  you can use `super` to bind it in child.

More reference consult: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#super

Comment: This is only half the correct answer, the other problem is the user should call `super().__init__(company)` instead of `BaseCompetition.__init__(self, company)`

Comment: Please add a comment regarding the `super()` change as it may not be clear to the original poster why it was changed. (you can link to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#super) as a reference).